# Cognos Analytics support for column organized table

Tags: ibm-cloud, cognos, dashdb

Are there any compatibility issues with Congos Analytics and column-organized tables?

I am getting the following error message from the Framework manager when I try to view data in a DashDB instance.....

> Data source adapter error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table.  Specified table: "GOSALES.COUNTRY".  Table type: "ORGANIZE BY COLUMN".  Operation: "WITH RS".. SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858, DRIVER=3.66.46 - when processing query: SELECT DISTINCT "COUNTRY"."COUNTRY_CODE" AS "COUNTRY_CODE" FROM "GOSALES"."COUNTRY" "COUNTRY" FOR FETCH ONLY.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is the `RS isolation`. Queries using the RR or RS isolation level are not supported with column-organized tables and the [WITH RS is a non-supported clause in that context](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059225.html?lang=en). So what you should do is to make sure the [isolation level is set to READ COMMITTED for the database connection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21666073).

[Cognos Analytics supports dashDB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_cognos.html) as well as DB2 with BLU Acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I followed the IBM instructions (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21666073) and set the isolation level of the connection to "Read Committed" in the Database Connection and that resolved my issue.

Comment: I added the link to the answer, great that it was resolved.